# Send InputBox data, entered by the user, to a simple table within access database

Tags: ms-access, datatable, user-input

I'm trying to figure out in VBA how I can add a function that the information that the user inputs into an inputbox is sent to a table, say Table_1, in my access database.

I would like each column to represent an inputbox, so if the user enters their name, it'll go directly into the column and table. Is this possible?

Comment: In Access, it is normal for data to be entered into tables through the use of forms that are based on them. Whilst it is possible to write data to a table using an InputBox, there is quite a lot of overhead involved, such as validating the data (if a number is required, has a number been entered?), and writing to the correct record if data is being updated.

Comment: Thank you - so if I have a simple one that is asking for a name, is there a basic VBA code to add to the inputbox that would then put it into a table in access?

Comment: Look at using a `Recordset` to `.AddNew` and `.Update`. Or else `DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO [TableName] ([FieldName]) SELECT 'data';"`.

Comment: I think I'm trying to do something way over my head as I'm so new to VBA in access. I have created an inputbox that will run, but when i put the following it gives me an error. Table name is AUSTable and the column I want info in is Name_and_Rank

    AddName = InputBox("What is your rank and full name?", "Enter Rank and Name")
    DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO [AUSTable] ([Name_and_Rank])"

Comment: It should read `DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO [AUSTable] ([Name_and_Rank]) SELECT ' " & strInput & " ';"`, where strInput is the result from your `InputBox`. I've left spaces between the single and double quotes to show you which is which - you need toremove these spaces in your code.

Comment: OH EXCELLENT! That worked! I did get a message pop up saying:

"You are about to append 1 row(s)

One you click "Yes", you can't use the Undo Command to reverse the changes, are you sure you want to append the selected rows?" If I select yes, it continues, but I don't necessarily want my users to have to select yes, every time.

Comment: The warning message can be turned off through removing the tick from Confirm Action Queries found in Options|Client Settings.

Comment: thank you so much! And I apologize, one more question - for now :) 

Is there a way so that the table is then cleared for the next time the functions are run? I don't need to store all the names, I would just like each field (the top row) to have the data stored there and then swipe cleaned before the next person opens the database to run

Comment: You can use `DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE * FROM [table];"` to delete all records from a table.

Comment: Great, so it would most likely benefit me to put that in the very beginning so that prior to each member inputting their data, previous data is cleared.

Comment: `CurrentDb.Execute ...` will not provoke warning popups.